# Regular expression in javascript, existence of character two types

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is a regular expression in JavaScript to check for the existence of characters from A to Z both lower and uppercase and 0 to 9 in a string.

```
var validChars = /[0-9a-zA-Z]/;
```

In addition to these characters I wanted to check for the existence of the `"@"` sign and the forward slash `"/"` in the same string.

For example, it will check for the existence of characters 0 to 9 and A to Z and `@` and `/` in a string.

How can this be done?

Comment: I think you should just learn regex (once and for all). If you understand what a character class does, then this should be very straight forward.

Comment: i am new to Javascript and regex, so if using this more often than one time it will be useful to learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add those characters to your class.

```
/^[a-z0-9@\/]+$/i
```

**Note**: You should probably use beginning of string `^` and end of string `$` anchors here, following your character class with a [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) and the `i` modifier can be used for case insensitive matching.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9@\/]*
```

Explanation

```
a-zA-Z: lower or upper case characters
0-9: numbers from 0 to 9
@: @
\/: /
*: zero or more machting. You can replace it with `+` for: one or more matching
```

[**Live demo**](http://regex101.com/r/nP2cH8/1)